# Dropwizard, Scribejava, Oauth 2.0 and Github

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, github-api, dropwizard, scribe

I'm attempting to authenticate with GitHub via oauth using the scribejava library in a Dropwizard (I guess jetty) application. I'm not overly sure of what I'm doing as I'm new to all this but I've hacked together the following resource class from a number of different blogs and examples.

```
@Path("/github")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class GithubResource {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GithubResource.class);

public static final String API_KEY = "APIKEY";

public static final String API_SECRET = "SECRETKEY";

private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://api.github.com/users";

private static final Token EMPTY_TOKEN = null;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response redirectToAuthorization() {

    OAuthService service = createService()
        .callback("https://localhost:8443/github/continue")
        .build();

    String authURL = service.getAuthorizationUrl(EMPTY_TOKEN);

    return Response.seeOther(URI.create(authURL)).build();
}

@GET
@Path("continue")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response redirectToApp(@QueryParam("client_id") String oauthToken, @QueryParam("code") String oauthVerifier) {

    OAuthService service = createService().build();

    Verifier verifier = new Verifier(oauthVerifier);

    Token requestToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);
    Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL, service);
    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);

    com.github.scribejava.core.model.Response response = request.send();

    return Response.ok(response.getBody()).build();
}


private ServiceBuilder createService() {
    return new ServiceBuilder()
        .provider(GitHubApi.class)
        .apiKey(API_KEY)
        .apiSecret(API_SECRET);
}
}
```

It's taken me a few days to get to this point but I can now successfully pull out the code from the response from github (I think) but then the app crashes with the following error log

```
ERROR [2015-11-23 03:12:37,417] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: fdf48e68be65c626
! com.github.scribejava.core.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this: 'error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fv3%2Foauth%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch2'
! at com.github.scribejava.core.extractors.TokenExtractor20Impl.extract(TokenExtractor20Impl.java:32) ~[scribejava-core-2.0.jar:na]
! at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20ServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth20ServiceImpl.java:37) ~[scribejava-core-2.0.jar:na]
! at org.squandered.generator.resource.GithubResource.redirectToApp(GithubResource.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
! at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
! at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
```

I see the "Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this" but I'm really not sure how I can correctly do this...

Does anyone see any obvious flaws with my code, or have a working example of using these libraries with oauth 2.0? Google seems to return results for oauth 1.0 which is a little different...

Appreciate any help in the right direction

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was actually a very simple bug, I wasn't pulling the correct param from the response URL in the callback method. Complete working example:

```
import com.github.scribejava.apis.GitHubApi;
import com.github.scribejava.core.builder.ServiceBuilder;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.Token;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.Verb;
import com.github.scribejava.core.model.Verifier;
import com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuthService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Random;

@Path("/github")
public class GithubResource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GithubResource.class);
    private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://api.github.com/user";
    private static final String API_KEY = "your key";
    private static final String API_SECRET = "your secret";
    private static final String CALL_BACK_URL = "https://localhost:8443/github/callback/";
    private static final Token EMPTY_TOKEN = null;

    @GET
    public Response getToken() {
        OAuthService service = createService().build();

        final String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(EMPTY_TOKEN);

        return Response.seeOther(URI.create(authorizationUrl)).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("callback")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response callback(@QueryParam("code") String oauthToken) {

        OAuthService service = createService().build();

        final Verifier verifier = new Verifier(oauthToken);

        final Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(EMPTY_TOKEN, verifier);
        final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL, service);
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);

        final com.github.scribejava.core.model.Response response = request.send();

        LOGGER.info("Response code: " + response.getCode());
        LOGGER.info("Response body: " + response.getBody());

        return Response.ok(response.getBody()).build();
    }

    private ServiceBuilder createService() {
        return new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(GitHubApi.class)
            .apiKey(API_KEY)
            .apiSecret(API_SECRET)
            .scope("repo")
            .state("secret" + new Random().nextInt(999_999))
            .callback(CALL_BACK_URL);
    }
}
```